# Store Excel Sheet (.xls) in DB2 database

Tags: c#, excel, db2

How do I store Excel Sheet / xls file to DB2 database using C# ? I need to store the sheet to save data and preserve the template. Will Read data / fetching file from db work for all data types i.e. Pictures / Charts /Graphs ? Any tutorial online ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to store the excel file as-is and not read the data it contains, you probably want to use the BLOB (Binary Large Object) datatype in DB2.  The IBM documentation for the .NET binding is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2BlobClass.html).

If you use a BLOB, you should be able to save and restore any type of object.

EDIT:

To read and write files to byte arrays, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array).  I don't have a DB2 instance up at the moment, but the standard ADO.NET methods for reading and writing large objects should work.  An example for SQL Server is [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3732256/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-3.htm), and you should be able to swap the SQL Server classes for the DB2 classes.

Comment: Provides info on how to ertrieve BLOB but not how to store an Excel Work Book as BLOB in DB2.