# Outofmemory exception when converting picture to byte array

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, stream, out-of-memory

I am working on Windows Phone and I need to convert the images in the phone to a byte array, but the problem is that VisualStudio throws an OutOfMemory exception.

Is there any way to avoid this error? Or an alternative way?

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(Picture p)
{
    byte[] buffer=new byte[p.GetImage().Length];
    p.GetImage().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Do not load such large of an image. Perhaps you could stream the image rather than load it into memory in one step.

Comment: you could pass the image to the byte array in chunks instead of all at once, maybe it'll help. Are you loading the picture from a folder? Or is it only in memory?

Comment: The image is located in a folder

Comment: I try to send the image using chunks, but now I don't know what happen that the stream sends more bytes than the total of the images :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found another way to upload images and now it doesn't throw exceptions. I decided to upload the file by chunks, just as Steven Mills. I would like to thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The image is too big for the memory.. Use `Stream` in `System.IO` to stream it and save it. That is the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MemoryStream such as :

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

See [How to convert image in byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array)