# how to insert image in DB in asp.net linq to entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to insert image in database and i have declared the binary(5000) datatype for it in the database.Please help me that how to convert image into bytes and how to store it in db ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert image in byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your image to byte array like this

```
        public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

and convert to image from byte[] like this

```
        public Image Convert_To_Image(object _ImageValue)
        {
            if (_ImageValue == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            byte[] imgArray = (byte[])_ImageValue;
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(imgArray);

            return Image.FromStream(mem);
        }
```

Assuming you have a picturebox and you want to show image in `picture box tool` you can do something like this

```
yourpicturebox.Image = Convert_To_Image(_ImageValue);
```

Comment: i have inserted binary data into db and now i want to show image on form. how can i convert that binary data into image using linq to entities ?

Comment: @AhmadRaza i have also add method `Convert_To_Image` in the answer which will convert binary  to image ..this method will return you image then you can show your image into your form

Comment: bro this is my code i am call it in a handler...where you think i am wrong ?        public static Stream  ShowProductImage(int id)
        {
            using (CRMEntities ctx = new CRMEntities())
            {
                var r = (from a in ctx.Products where a.id == id select a).First();
                return new MemoryStream(r.image.ToArray());
            }
        }

Comment: Please tell me that where i should write connection string for http generic handler and in which form ?

Comment: @AhmadRaza You should keep connection string in config file