# How to convert gif images to jpeg in c# code winforms?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, crystal-reports

I am trying to convert my gif/png images to jpeg then after that i want to pass
  these images to sqldatabase. Because crystal report doesnot support gif images
  for displaying as a report.

So now i have a problem to covert gif images to jpeg.

Sample code:

```
data = File.ReadAllBytes(ImgPath);
```

data is byte[] type so i have image path now i want to convert into jpeg
    before ReadAllBytes() callls

I tried like this :

```
   using (Image img = Image.FromFile(ImgPath))
   {
             img.Save(ImgPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
```

But i got Generic error Gdi something is came.
   thanks.

Comment: Where is the error? in the Image.FromFile or in img.Save?

Comment: @bdn02 img.save() method. I got this error

Comment: Your error is because you opened the image, kept it open, and then tried to save it over itself (while open) as a new format.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```
        byte[] imagebuffer;

        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp_10\sample.gif"))
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            imagebuffer = ms.ToArray();
        }

        //write to fs (if you need...)
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp_10\sample.jpg", imagebuffer);
```

The namespace to use is System.Drawing

I've modified my code, i think that you don't need the file on filesystem but you can use the byte array to call Crystal report

Comment: What error? Are you sure that the original file is a gif?

Comment: i got an error like this : A generic error occured in GDI+

Comment: Check if your application has permissions to read/write those files

Comment: 4.5 version before that it's working good. before converting an format. directly get the path and store the image good. but now there is a problem

Comment: _I  got an error like this : A generic error occured in GDI+_ __On which line???__

Answer (score 0):

Here are two places that can help.  One is Microsoft's site on how to read in image files to memory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0(v=vs.90).aspx

The next is an example from another user on the site on how to read the file into a bite array as the format you want.  I am assuming you want it as a byte array so you can do something with it rather than put it back down as a file.

[How to convert image in byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array)

I would have typed it all out but found the examples and they were self explanatory.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go even simpler than [bdn02's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35079205/7311767) answer. Try:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp_10\sample.gif");
img.Save(@"c:\temp_10\sample.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```