# How can I make the ImageToByteArray function to be more generic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image, memorystream

I have two methods which convert an image from and to a byte array, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array) on StackOverflow.

```
Public Function ImageToByteArray(imageIn As Image) As Byte()
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Function

Public Function ByteArrayToImage(byteArrayIn As Byte()) As Image
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)
    Dim returnImage As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
    Return returnImage
End Function
```

Both work fine when my image is a png file. But when the user selects a jepg file or gif I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'`

How can I make the ImageToByteArray function to be more generic? i.e. Accept more file formats.

Comment: Have you tried using the .RawFormat property instead of hardcoding it in the .Save ?

Comment: @the_lotus Could you explain your comment more fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8) class has a property called [RawFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rawformat?view=netframework-4.8), you can try and use it instead of hardcoding the format.

```
    Public Function ImageToByteArray(imageIn As Image) As Byte()
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat)
        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Function
```

If this doesn't work, you'll need to pass the format as parameter.

```
    Public Function ImageToByteArray(imageIn As Image, format As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As Byte()
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat)
        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Function
```

Comment: ...with imageIn.RawFormat, I can take a gif or a png but jpeg still causes an error.

Comment: @Randy hmmmm, not sure what is happening for this case.