# Converting byte array to image in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, memorystream

I have converted an image(.tif image) to a byte array and saved in the DB. I am now retrieving that byte array from the DB and want to convert to an image again, but this byte array I am converting back to an image, is not producing the same. As a test (as below), I am only using the image and not reading from the DB, for testing purposes.

The initial convert from Image to byte array:

```
//This is the function I am using:
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

//Converting to byte array:
var tifImage = Image.FromFile(file.ToString());
var imageContent = ImageToByteArray(tifImage);
```

Now to try and convert back to an Image, I am doing the following:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageContent);
var test1 = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

But it seems the results are not the same. I have a "Splitting" function that splits the pages within the tiff, and the one returns 8 pages(bitmaps) and the other just 1.

I dont know much about the above, so need a little help in filling in the knowledge gaps, please :)

Thanks for any the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16958128/7772646 You could look at this answer for the converting and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Thanks for the response BrightHammer - This seems to be Image to `Bytes[]`, my issue is from `Bytes[]` to `Image` that is not the same :(

Comment: Axle, I think the problem is occurring when you convert it to bytes not when you recreate the image from the bytes.

Comment: Anything is a possibility, I will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: I gave the solution a try by replacing my current `ImageToByteArray`, but the result is still incorrect when converting `Byte[]` back to Image :( Im sure I have to be missing something small, but all the research I do shows that I am doing the right things :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that ended up working. It seems that when the initial `ImageToByteArray` was being done, it was only doing the "1st page" and not all 8. So I used the following code to convert the whole tiff image:

```
var tiffArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file); //The `file` is the actual `.tiff` file
```

I then used the following to convert back to an image(The `response` is a `byte[]` returned from our `API`):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(response))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

                var splitImages = ImageHelper.Split(returnImage);//This is to split the pages within the tiff
            }
```

I read that for the above to work(and I tested it), anything you do to the `byte[]`you are converting back to an image, must be done within the `using`, as anything after the `using` means the `image` is disposed.