# How to I convert to image from Byte[] Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, winforms, datagridview

I am making a face recognition project. I insert a person with face image and it assigned to variable and I use variable in database.

I am inserting image to database and dataGridView. When I insert a image, it writes "Byte[] Array" on dataGridView. How to I convert to image on dataGridView or how to I send to pictureBox ? It is enough one of both.

Variable of face image and convert

```
 Image img = pictureBox2.Image;
 byte[] arr;
 ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
 arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
```

İnsert to database

```
ESG("insert into kisiler values('" + textFaceName.Text + "','" + textFaceSurname.Text + "','" + textNationality.Text + "', '" + int.Parse(textAge.Text) + "','" + cinsiyet + "','"+ arr +"')");
```

Comment: FYI your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterised queries.

Comment: To convert an image to a Byte array - take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801289/9365244.

Comment: Also this is fragile against table columns being reordered

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use the following code to convert Byte Array to Image:

```
Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn));
```

Which you can put it in a function like this:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     Image returnImage = null;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
     {
         returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     }
     return returnImage;
}
```

You can also convert your Byte Array to string and use it to bind a PictureBox like the following code. Actually, I've used it in WebApp projects and not sure if it works on yours:

```
string photo = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray.Photo, 0, byteArray.Photo.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

From PictureBox to DB (VB Code)

```
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create("profile.jpg")
ProfilePictureBox.Image.Save(fs, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
fs.Close()
fs = File.OpenRead("profile.jpg")
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
fs.CopyTo(ms)

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@profilePic", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = ms.ToArray()
```

From Db To PictureBox (VB Code)

```
Dim readByte As Byte() = sqlReader("IMG_BYTE")
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(readByte)
PictureBox1.Image= Image.FromStream(ms)
```

From Db To DatagridView (VB Code)

```
Dim img As Image    
Dim readByte As Byte() = sqlReader("IMG_BYTE")
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(readByte)
img = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

Comment: Please use `using`s. Incidentally, VarBinary can be passed directly from a stream enclosed in `SqlBytes`

Answer (score 0):

A user named rajantawate1 in [this codeproject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv) provided the following code:

```
   public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
           imageIn.Save(ms,imageIn.RawFormat);
            return  ms.ToArray();
         }
    }
```