# Converting .net Image to byte array without the header

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I want to search in an image for pixels above or below a certain value once that image has been read from a file and [converted to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array). The Count method for a byte array is quite fast:

```
int numHighSaturatedPixels = imageArray.Count(n => n == highThreshold)
```

but the header information from the image format (BMP in my case) is still in there and is included in the count.  How can the image be converted to a byte array without the header data getting in there?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801291) in the question you already looked at. That uses the WPF API. I've added other duplicates that include GDI+ and `LockBits` as well, since it's not clear in your question which API you want to use.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the confusion, I'm using WinForms.  The CopyPixels method isn't in Bitmap in that case.

Comment: That's okay... you can still use the other methods, like `LockBits()`.

Comment: Tried the solution suggested by @PeterDuniho and it works perfectly.  [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=net-5.0) has a good example that I followed.  Thanks, Peter!