# Writing additional bytes to picture c#

Tags: c#, image, byte

The task is to take a picture, read all its bytes and then write additional 15 zero bytes after each non-zero byte from original file. Example: it was B1,B2,...Bn and after it must be B1,0,0,..0,B2,0,0..,Bn,0,0..0. Then I need to save/replace new picture. In general I assume I can use something like ReadAllBytes and create an array of bytes, then create new byte[] array and take one byte from file, then write 15 zero bytes, then take second byte and etc. But how can I be sure that it is working correctly? I'm not familiar with working with bytes and if I try to print bytes that I've read from file it shows some random symbols that don't make any sense which leaves the question: am I doing it right? If possible, please direct me to right approach and the functions that I need to use to achieve it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your current code (just as less as possible, as much as relevant), the expected outcome and what you expect instead.

Comment: Write a test. That's how you verify software.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to convert image to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array) for how to read the image.

It seems that you'd like to be able to visually see the data. For debugging purposes, you can show each byte as a hex string which will allow you to "see" the hex values of each element of your array.

```
public string GetBytesAsHexString(byte[] bArr)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (bArr != null && bArr.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bArr.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", bArr[i].ToString("X"), System.Environment.NewLine);
            //sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", bArr[i].ToString("X2"), System.Environment.NewLine);
            //sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", bArr[i].ToString("X4"), System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```