# How to deserialize json image(byet array)into image in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, image, web-services

My json Array:

```
   {" lstFooddtlResult":[{"class_name":"Veg","food_name":"pizza","food_photo":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1........],"food":"12","qty_uom":"Pcs","unit":null}]}
```

C# Class:

```
public class Food{
    public string class_name { get; set; }
    public string food_name { get; set; }
    public photo[] photo { get; set; }
    public int food { get; set; }
    public string qty_uom { get; set; }
    public string unitcost { get; set; }

}

    public class photo{
    public byte food_photo { get; set; }
}

    public class FooddtlResult{
    public Food[] lstFooddtlResult { get; set; }
}
```

**My Questions are:**

1. Is My c# class is correct?
2. How to convert byte-array into  image in c# asp.net?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid (check it with http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Duplicate of [Bytearray to image conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/bytearray-to-image-conversion) ?

Comment: i missed the bracket in json data....i wann'a complete code to convert byte array to image in asp.net c#@paolo,istern