# Binary Array to image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deserialize json image(byet array)into image in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250000/how-to-deserialize-json-imagebyet-arrayinto-image-in-asp-net)

The byte array gets converted into the **integer representation** of each byte. When viewed in Fiddler it look likes

```
 {"imageBackground":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,...]}
```

How to retrieve this **integer image array** from **json web service**  as class in asp.net c#

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a byte array:

```
byte[] imageBackground = new byte[] { 137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,... };
```

you could create an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx):

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBackground))
using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream))
{
    // do something with the image
}
```

or if you wanted to display it on an ASP.NET web form, inside an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) control, you could write a generic handler that will stream this image to the response:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        byte[] imageBackground = new byte[] { 137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,... };
        response.OutputStream.Write(imageBackground, 0, imageBackground.Length);
        response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    }
}
```

and then point the Image control to this generic handler:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="myimage" ImageUrl="~/imagehandler.ashx" />
```