# Store and retrieve images from database using path

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created a windows form application to scan any document.After the image is scanned i am saving it in form of bytes in a folder in the system.Now i want to retrieve the image from database giving the path of the folder.whether it is possible or not.If possible plz help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bytearray to image conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/bytearray-to-image-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Source : [C# Image to Byte Array and Byte Array to Image Converter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)