# how to convert binary data to image and display in Div Tag or img Tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, blob

I am converting my image to binary data and storing in binary format with this:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"F:\Image\Img1.jpg");
```

My database field for storing image is: **Varbinary(Max)**

Now i am reading this binary data from my database and i am getting binary data.

I want to display image in this Div tag.

This is my View:

```
 <div class="Image-ad"></div>
```

My Class:

```
 public class ImageAdd   
 {
        public Guid ImageAddId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
 }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var data=db.ImageAdd.ToList();    
   return View(db);
}
```

How to convert this binary data to image and display in Div Tag???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bytearray to image conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/bytearray-to-image-conversion)

Comment: @lloydm:but this is different as because i want to display in my div tag too

Comment: why can't you use `img` tag? you can wrap `img` tag with `div`.

Comment: @ramiramilu:i take it your suggestion and i would like to consider as what you have said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options:

1 : add this to image div

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" />
```

and you'r done!

2: another way is to add a simple method to your controller and call it in your view to display the image tag.
add this method to your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(byte[] data) 
{
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data)
  return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

and in view add this line to image div:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "MyController", new { data = Model.Image })" />
```

Comment: i dont want this as a seperate method

Comment: @MariaPithia whay not?? this method will convert binary data to an image to correctly display in your view. if you don't like it, just use the first way.

Comment: this method would call independently no as my main view will be loaded or would be called on any click event ?

Comment: please test it, this method will render image on page load.

Comment: this controller method is not calling on my page load

Comment: your approach 1 worked correctly and image is getting rendered but your i quite liked your approach 2 but problem is my controller method is not calling

Comment: please try Html.RenderAction instead of Url.Action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78164/discussion-between-maria-pithia-and-iman-nemati).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a canvas tag to load the image inside it and render it that way, we did this for previewing uploaded images in a recent project.