# Convert Image from Byte Array to Image from MS Access using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Are there any way to convert Image which is stored in MS Access to byte array using C#? Currently, I have stored my Image into my database which is in byte array format. Now I want to use OleDbReader to read through my image as a byte array, but I dont know how to it.

This is my Insert image into database code:

```
private byte[] ConvertToDBFormat(IImage InputImage)
    {
        Bitmap BmpImage = new Bitmap(InputImage.Bitmap);
        MemoryStream MyStream = new MemoryStream();
        BmpImage.Save(MyStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] ImageAsBytes = MyStream.ToArray();
        return ImageAsBytes;
    }
```

This is my code where I want to read from the database as byte

```
byte[] buffer = (byte[])reader["FaceImage"];
```

Comment: And what happens with that current code? Are you able to get the `byte[]` correctly? (Hint: you can construct a `MemoryStream` from a `byte[]`...)

Comment: well yes i can get the `byte[]` correctly, but I dont really know how to convert it to image format using `MemoryStream`

Comment: Well have you looked at all the members of the `Bitmap` class, such as the `Bitmap(Stream)` constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/bytearray-to-image-conversion

Comment: simply use it to get the image: `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `byte[]` to a Bitmap using `MemoryStream`
like this:

```
private Bitmap ConvertToBitmapFormat(byte[] buffer)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(stream, false);
        return image;
    }
```