# How to Convert and display only the first page from Multipage Blob .Tiff image to .Jpeg using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image, bitmap

I am pretty much newer in asp.net MVC. My core objective is to Convert the .tiff image to .jpeg format without saving as file. For that i call separate file(ex:gettiff.aspx) for showing .tiff image in browser.

What i have done?
I was saved the multipage .tiff image into DB as blob.

What i need?
Need to show that multipage .tiff image by converting to .Jpeg in View

What i successfully done?
To convert single page .tiff image(File/Blob), i don't have any problem in conversion as .jpeg and viewed as well in VIEW

Where i stuck?
To convert multipage .tiff image(File/Blob), i have problem during the conversion as .Jpeg and viewed as well in VIEW

Sample Code:
C#: In gettiff.aspx file

```
while (Reader.Read())
                        {
                            Bitmap bImage = ByteToImage((byte[])Reader["refImage"]);                               
                            byte[] array1 = ImageToByte2(myBmp);
                        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; // if your image is a jpeg of course
                        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])array1);

                        }
```

Convert Blob to Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
{
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
        mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
        return bm;
    }
}
```

Convert bitmap to bytearray (this will gives as .jpeg format)

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Bitmap img)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            }
            return byteArray;
        }
```

In View:

```
<img src="../GetTiffImage.aspx?batchImageId=@item.RefImgId&&ImgType=CBlob" width="150" height="100" style=" border:groove;border-color: #ff0000;" />
```

I need to convert as .jpeg and display only the first page from that multi page .tiff blob.

Problem occurred while saving the stream - *"A generic error occurred in GDI+"*

Anybody can help me...

Answer (score 0):

I Found Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion). By getting that single line code i can able to display .tiff blob image

Sample Code:

```
public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
        {
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(blob));
            return bm;
        }
```

Instead of using Memory Stream, if i use this conversion will able to get the image in View. Remaining codes are same from the question