# Varbinary to file conversion

Tags: c#

I have downloaded attachments from salesforce to sql server using DBAMP salesforce data integration tool.

However the actual attachment gets stored as binary bytes in a IMAGE dataype column.

I am trying to export data in image to a file but have unsuccessful so far
using SQL CLR function below and example of varbinary value to be converted to test.jpg.Can someone please help

0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFEC00114475636B7900010004000000500000FFEE002641646F62650064C0000000010300150403060A0D00000236000002E10000039F00000494FFDB0084000202020202020202020203020202030403020203040504040404040506050505050505060607070807070609090A0A09090C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C01030303050405090606090D0B090B0D0F0E0E0E0E0F0F0C0C0C0C0C0F0F0C0C0C0C0C0C0F0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0CFFC20011080016001903011100021101031101FFC400B300010101000000000000000000000000000607050101010101000000000000000000000000050403061000010303020505000000000000000000010203040010051112214132131422233415061100020102040502070000000000000000010203110400213112104132131422058292B223337315120002020301000000000000000000000000011011213102A113010002010400060301000000000000000111210010314151F0618191A1C171D1F1E1FFDA000C030100021103110000015BDEF17B93ED9FB662933F5E2AEEBCEB9197C6317C290F42AC329237083F6C7FFFDA0008010100010502932A435231917319632D125A353BE6FE77C0FA35F8DBAA534DAE4605B427081086D8AFFFDA00080102000105024A010EADB6E9B20D9BE993BBB89D6C93C241F735D4D7FFDA000801030001050252882DA56E52C1165F547DBDB3A59438B03D1CABFFDA0008010202063F02B3284D42178737B8D1C8A3FFDA0008010302063F0230C69C318EA7A1C7FFDA0008010101063F029A18A778A385CA22231514534E5897C6BC755869BDE495C0CF9655C5FD9DE4DE43DAAAB07DC5A87720C89CF46E177FBA4FA8E2FBF2743FF47E53D3F0E3DCFC4DDE376876B7F553B91EBC26737290BB3B192270F556AE63D2AC35C7BE01708E1A37AB8DF41F6CEB5518BAD9289D99006D9501577AE7EA0BCE9C3FFFDA0008010103013F212F5DF020523AC2204B219C0B16BAC1711CE56A521B9A2C6148687988F05E78E9CF8B937D11D44E255CC04A11C8C3627B34A7B0E547FEA63A962C0403BE9FFFDA0008010203013F212A815C89E4E8320BC4FA70FEB4F80675DC7F5EB9EAAFA7470927DBEE319ADDCEBBFCE0A511FC7A9D3FFFDA0008010303013F21600C064F7079E49398FF003F7A7C873EC3FCF4CFC5C7D9A02AE3DFEB00BBC462044CFF004EF4FFDA000C030100021103110000104E56F30A6FFFDA0008010103013F10AD573F3CE1524ADADB90C48356D25C135022D249212F8595861282024DAB24EDF6D0682804D150CBF5617B50B061BE1CB2727CDC4D6E26C2BEC2C4C00901614605426789E758291E2F64B604EE8580CBCFFFDA00080102

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Text;

namespace BlobExport
{
    public class Functions
    {
        [SqlFunction]
        public static SqlString WriteToFile(SqlBytes binary, SqlString path)
        {
            try
            {

                byte[] byteArr = binary.Value;
                string filepath = path.Value;
                    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, byteArr);


                    return "SUCCESS";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly it the problem with the code you have? *"but have unsuccessful so far"* is not a very specific description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte Array to Image Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)

Comment: The problem is It's generating 1kb corrupted file