# How to Display DICOM images using EvilDICOM in c#?

Tags: c#, image, evil-dicom

I want to use EvilDICOM library to work on some dicom images. Now I am trying to show an image in a PictureBox in C#. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work with gray images without compression. I used the function ImageFromRawBgraArray from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)

```
   public void loadImage(string fileName)
    {

        var dcm = EvilDICOM.Core.DICOMObject.Read(fileName);
        string photo = dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION).DData.ToString();
        ushort bitsAllocated = (ushort)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.BITS_ALLOCATED).DData;
        ushort highBit = (ushort)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.HIGH_BIT).DData;
        ushort bitsStored = (ushort)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.BITS_STORED).DData;
        double intercept =(double) dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.RESCALE_INTERCEPT).DData;
        double slope = (double)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.RESCALE_SLOPE).DData;
        ushort rows = (ushort)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.ROWS).DData;
        ushort colums = (ushort)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.COLUMNS).DData;
        ushort pixelRepresentation = (ushort)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.PIXEL_REPRESENTATION).DData;
        List<byte> pixelData = (List<byte>)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.PIXEL_DATA).DData_;
        double window = (double)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.WINDOW_WIDTH).DData;
        double level = (double)dcm.FindFirst(TagHelper.WINDOW_CENTER).DData;
        int minVal = 0;
        int maxVal = 255;

        if (!photo.Contains("MONOCHROME"))//just works for gray images
            return;

        int index = 0;
        byte[] outPixelData = new byte[rows * colums * 4];//rgba
        ushort mask = (ushort)(ushort.MaxValue >> (bitsAllocated - bitsStored));
        double maxval = Math.Pow(2, bitsStored);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.Count; i+=2)
        {
            ushort gray = (ushort)((ushort)(pixelData[i]) + (ushort)(pixelData[i + 1] << 8));
            double valgray = gray & mask;//remove not used bits

            if (pixelRepresentation == 1)// the last bit is the sign, apply a2 complement
            {
                if (valgray > (maxval / 2))
                    valgray = (valgray - maxval);

            }

            valgray = slope * valgray + intercept;//modality lut


            //This is  the window level algorithm
            double half = ((window - 1) / 2.0) - 0.5;

            if (valgray <= level - half)
                valgray = 0;
            else if (valgray >= level + half)
                valgray = 255;
            else
                valgray = ((valgray - (level - 0.5)) / (window - 1) + 0.5) * 255;

            outPixelData[index] =(byte)valgray;
            outPixelData[index + 1] = (byte)valgray;
            outPixelData[index + 2] = (byte)valgray;
            outPixelData[index + 3] = 255;

            index += 4;
        }


        Image newimage = this.ImageFromRawBgraArray(outPixelData, colums, rows);
        pictureBox1.Image = newimage;
    }


    public Image ImageFromRawBgraArray(
       byte[] arr, int width, int height)
    {
        var output = new Bitmap(width, height);
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var bmpData = output.LockBits(rect,
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, output.PixelFormat);
        var ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, arr.Length);
        output.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return output;
    }
```