# Get image width and height from a byte array data

Tags: c#, arrays, image, unity-game-engine

I have a byte[] array which reads a local file and then I assign it to a unity Texture2D.  The image is assigned using the im.sprite = Sprite.Create() function.

The problem I have is that I need to detect the width and height of the image from the byte array so I can adjust adjust the texture size and avoid image stretching on the unity scene at run-time.

Do you know how I could use a library or function of some kind to maybe create a temp image from the image byte array and then see the desired width and height before I create the sprite and apply the texture?

I've found solutions in Java but can't seen to get it working by adapting in c#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte Array to Image Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)

Comment: @Mat It is not a duplicate. This is Unity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `Texture2D.LoadImage` is called, it will automatically replace the `Texture2D` instance with the size of the image. You can then grab the width and height from the `Texture2D` instance and pass it to the `Sprite.Create` function.

Load your image to byte array

```
byte[] imageBytes = loadImage(savePath);
```

Create new Texture2D

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
```

Load it into a Texture2D.
After LoadImage is called, 2x2 will be replaced with the size of that image.

```
texture.LoadImage(imageBytes);
```

Your image component

```
Image im = GetComponent<Image>();
```

You can create a new `Rect` with it and then pass it to your Sprite function to create new `Sprite`.

```
im.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Read more about the `Texture2D.LoadImage` function [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html).

You just need [`Texture2D.width`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-width.html) and [`Texture2D.height`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-height.html) variables.