# .NET-Core byte array to Image

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

how do I convert a `byte[]` to an Image in .NET Core?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
{
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

but it seems like `Image` doesnt exist in `.NET-Core`.

Comment: No indeed it is not released yet. you can use the library ImageSharp

Comment: oh thats weird. If you would answer this question I could mark it as correct

Comment: The code from the question works fine now in `.NET-Core`.

Comment: @ZbigniewWiadro nice to hear that :-) You should probably answer this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No indeed it is not released yet. you can use the library [ImageSharp](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp).

Answer (score 3):

To return an image from a byte array, you can either:

1. return base64

   ```
   Byte[] profilePicture = await _db.Players
                                    .Where(p => p.Id == playerId)
                                    .Select(p => p.ProfilePicture)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

   return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(profilePicture));
   ```

   And then you can use any [online tool](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) that converts base64 to image to test it.
2. or return [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType)

   ```
   return File(profilePicture, "image/png");
   ```

   You should be able to test this from Postman or anything similar as the picture will show up in the body of the response there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the **System.Drawing.Common** NuGet package.
Then you may use next function:

```
    public static System.Drawing.Image ImageFromByteArray(byte[] src)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(src);
        System.Drawing.Image retval = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        return retval;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using javascript

img tag:

html

```
<img id="logoPic" src="" />
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("logoPic").src = "data:image/png;base64," + yourByte;
```

with insertCell:

```
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "<img src='" + "data:image/png;base64," + yourByte + "'></>";
```

with td:

```
"<td>"+ "<img src='" + "data:image/png;base64," + yourByte + "'></>" + "</td>"
```

If you are using jquery:

html

```
<img id="logoPic" src="" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#logoPic').attr('src', `data:image/png;base64,${YourByte}`);
```

Comment: this question about dotnet core dear @carlos