# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred From Datagrid to Another Winform

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to cast an image from a Datagridview and display into a form which i have set its modifiers to public. I get this Error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]'
>   to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.

on this line

```
           InformationForm info = new InformationForm();
        info.visit_date.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        info.visitor_name.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        info.sign_intime.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        info.vehicle_number.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        info.organization.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        info.visit_type.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        info.reason.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        info.id_type.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        info.person_visit.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        info.pictureBox.Image = byteArrayToImage(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value); // on this line
        info.ShowDialog();
```

And it does not show in the picturebox. What am i getting wrong?

Comment: What you're getting wrong is trying to cast an object of the type `System.Byte[]` to type `System.Drawing.Image`, as the error message suggests. If what's in those bytes is actually a serialized image, you'll have to find some way to construct an Image object from the bytes. That should be doable with a little searching. It's also possible that you're looking in the wrong cell; I have no way of guessing what's in your datagridview.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion) or provide more information about how your data is saved inside the datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast `System.Byte[]` to `Image`, you have to create a new `Image` object. Try it like this:

```
info.pictureBox.Image = byteArrayToImage((byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value);
```

And here's the method:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
     Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

     return img;
}
```

Comment: Error : cannot convert from Object to byte[]

Comment: @Markaz: I added a cast to `byte[]`. Please try it again and tell me if it works. If not, I guess I'll have to delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would work well for you:

Since you have a image as byte array from a database or somewhere and you just need to convert and show it:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value))
{
    info.pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks All the same :)