# Convert byte[] to Bitmap in Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had a project working well in .Net 4.6.2, which makes heavy usage of converting byte[] to Bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap ByteArrayToImage(byte[] source)
    {
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
        return (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(source);
    }
```

However, I have since upgraded projects to .Net Core 2.1 and this no longer works. I've read, and a few people have issues, but battling to find a fix.

> TypeConverter cannot convert from System.Byte[]

Is there a way in 2.1 to achieve this conversion?
It looks like https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp might work, but when I search for it in Nuget, I get no results.

Comment: I'd probably just create a `MemoryStream` from the byte array, and then create a `Btitmap` from the stream.

Comment: `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(source)) {return new Bitmap(ms);}`

Comment: Thanks guys. That worked. If you put an answer, I can mark it done. Nice one, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte Array to Image Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to put the `bytes` into a `MemoryStream`

```
public static Bitmap ByteArrayToImage(byte[] source)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(source))
    {
        return new Bitmap(ms);
    }
}
```

The code above will use the `Bitmap(Stream stream)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in 2.1 to achieve this conversion? It looks like https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp might work, but when I search for it in Nuget, I get no results.

Yes, you can use this open source for your problem, but you can't get it via nuget. At the moment, you need [MyGet](https://www.myget.org) to get that package. You can refer this link to know how to use ImageSharp packages: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

Otherwise, you can convert your byte array to MemoryStream first:

```
    public static Bitmap ByteArrayToImage(byte[] source)
    {
        return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(source));
    }
```