# How can I insert an image from SQL Server onto a button in VB.net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am having issues assigning an image to every button according to my database.

My current code:

```
 Dim strsql As String
 Dim ImgSQl As Image

 Dim con As New SqlConnection("constring")
 con.Open()

 strsql = "SELECT Image FROM Inventory WHERE ID=@ID"

 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strsql, con)

 ItemID = 1
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ItemID
 Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
    
 myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 myreader.Read()
 ImgSQl = myreader("Image")
 con.Close()

 btn1.Image = ImgSQl
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Byte array to image conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)

Comment: @jumexmango In answers to previous questions of yours, there were details about `Using` for SqlClient objects, but you're still using `Dim` in this latest question.

Comment: @HardCode That's true, I will change `Dim con` to `Using con` for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was dim as Byte, also adding "()" is really important for it to work. Hope answering my own question helps a VB.net beginner out there.

```
   Dim strsql As String
   Dim ImgSql() As Byte
    
     Using con As New SqlConnection("constring")
     con.Open()
    
     strsql = "SELECT Image FROM Inventory WHERE ID=@ID"
    
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strsql, con)
    
     ItemID = 1
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ItemID
     Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        
     myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
     myreader.Read()
     ImgSql = myreader("Imagen")
     Dim ms As New MemoryStream(ImgSql)
     btn1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
     con.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: Connections are precious resources. Please don't open a connection until directly before the command is executed. DataReaders also need to be disposed so, add a Using block for your reader. Just noticed that you have failed to put your command in a Using also.

Comment: You don't have to close you connection. The End Using will handle that for you.

Comment: @Mary I will start placing my connections better. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: You can create the connection object just as you have done. Just don't call the `Open` method until just before the `Execute...`.